# Creating network

Tags: matlab

I  am looking to create a simple network with source and destination nodes within MATLAB. The sources node sends packets with size varies from 512 to 1024, and once the link is wired then a wireless in order to compute the delay in these different situations.
I am really don't know from where to start here.

I am relatively new at MATLAB  so any help would be very useful!

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more information and details about your problem ? do you have a pseudo code did you start implementing an algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial about it is [How to create your own network](http://www.stanford.edu/group/pdplab/pdphandbook/handbookap2.html).

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have a pseudo code, cause it is the first step I should do is to create a network with a source node that started from known position then it moves to another location with continuity of sending packets with different size to the destination.